# How to perform HTTP 303 redirect with urllib2 in Python?

Tags: python, redirect, urllib2, http-error

I have a URL to fetch, that gives a HTTP 303 redirect :

```
import urllib2 as web
import sys

url='http://sample.com'

try: handle=web.urlopen(url)
except web.HTTPError, e:
  print e.code
  sys.exit(1)
data=handle.read()
print 'Result :'
print data
```

So, the above code prints `303` as a result, it's a 303 redirect.

I want that it should follow the redirect and fetch me the HTML of the destination.

### Edit

```
curl -I http://my303redirecturl.com/
```

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Date: Tue, 23 Aug 2011 04:53:53 IST
Server: Mule Core/3.1.2
Expires: Tue, 23 Aug 2011 04:53:53 IST
http.status: 303
Content-Type: application/json
MULE_ENCODING: UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
```

Will this help ?

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: Python Version = Python 2.6.6

Comment: With cPython 2.6.7, I can't reproduce the problem. Can you try the demo code in my answer and report back what results that gives you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

urllib2 should follow 303 redirects by default. Use the following example to test:

```
import urllib2
url = 'http://phihag.de/2011/so/303/'
print(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
```

If the above code prints out the content of example.net, but your URL doesn't, the URL in question is not resolving to a correct 303 redirect. If that is the case, you can use [`urllib2.build_opener`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.build_opener) to get an opener that uses your own implementation of [`BaseHandler`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#basehandler-objects) instead of the default [`HTTPRedirectHandler`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#httpredirecthandler-objects).

Comment: I want it to get the data from the re-directed url.

Comment: @Yugal Jindle That means your URL is not performing a correct 303 redirect. Can you post it? Note that for the URL `http://phihag.de/2011/so/303/`, which is a valid 303 redirect, "getting the data from the re-directed URL" is precisely what the Python code in this answer does.

Comment: @Yugal Jindle Then walk to the administrator/developer of that server and hit him in the face with the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4) ;) Also, if you want us to help you, you'll have to give us something, for example the output of `curl -I URL.in/your/network` or so.

Comment: I have added the output of Curl -I url

Comment: @Yugal Jindle As I predicted, that's not a valid HTTP 303 response, it's missing the `Location:` HTTP header. This header contains the URL  that the redirect goes to. Since it's simply not there, there's no way a Python or any other program (or even human) could follow that redirect. Contact the administrator/developer of that server.

Comment: Well, I sorted out the error with the other developer.
But, I don't understand that how were chrome and firefox were able to fetch the json response from the 303 url.

Comment: @Yugal Jindle The server probably reacts differently based on what the HTTP headers are, for example `Accept:`, `User-Agent:`. That's still no excuse to send invalid HTTP (if the headers are somehow lacking, the correct way to indicate that is a 4xx status code, like 400), or a 500 if a programming error (like expecting an `Accept` header in the request, and causing a `KeyError`) has occured.

Comment: @phihag you're mistaken. Yugal is correct when saying your code example returns a 303 instead of the URL. Look at your code again. You're handling the HTTPError object, then printing the error code (which is 303). You should be printing the error message using e.read().

Comment: @diq Humor me and actually run the code and see what output you're getting. The `except` was copied from the question and is not needed here - the `except` clause will not be executed unless there is a connection problem. I've therefore updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html) page provides a pretty good summary on how to handle HTTP redirects with urllib.

HTH

**EDIT:** The article shows how to retrieve the redirection URL, which can then be requested with another `urlopen`.

Comment: It talks about detecting them, not what I have asked.

Comment: It shows how you detect the redirects, that is true. But it also explains how you retrieve the redirected URL, which you can now request with an additional `urlopen`.